# Copy (over a web API) is complete; I get a broken pipe anyway. How to solve it?

Tags: java, box-api, broken-pipe

For [one of my projects](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-box), I implement a Java 7 `FileSystem` over the Box API Java SDK (the [new one](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk)).

However, for downloading files, when you want to have a stream to the content, it only provides methods taking `OutputStream` as an argument; specifically, I am using [this one](http://opensource.box.com/box-java-sdk/javadoc/com/box/sdk/BoxFile.html#download(java.io.OutputStream)) at the moment.

But this doesn't sit well with the JDK API; I need to be able to implement [`FileSystemProvider#newInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html#newInputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)... Therefore I elected to use `Pipe{Input,Output}Stream`.

Moreover, since the Box SDK API methods are synchronous (not that it matters here), I wrap them in a `Future`. My code is as follows (imports ommitted for brevity):

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public final class BoxFileInputStream
    extends InputStream
{
    private final Future<Void> future;
    private final PipedInputStream in;

    public BoxFileInputStream(final ExecutorService executor,
        final BoxFile file)
    {
        in = new PipedInputStream(16384);
        future = executor.submit(new Callable<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public Void call()
                throws IOException
            {
                try {
                    file.download(new PipedOutputStream(in));
                    return null;
                } catch (BoxAPIException e) {
                    throw BoxIOException.wrap(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int read()
        throws IOException
    {
        try {
            return in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            throw new BoxIOException("download failure", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read(final byte[] b)
        throws IOException
    {
        try {
            return in.read(b);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            throw new BoxIOException("download failure", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len)
        throws IOException
    {
        try {
            return in.read(b, off, len);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            throw new BoxIOException("download failure", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(final long n)
        throws IOException
    {
        try {
            return in.skip(n);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            throw new BoxIOException("download failure", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int available()
        throws IOException
    {
        try {
            return in.available();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            throw new BoxIOException("download failure", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
        throws IOException
    {
        IOException streamException = null;
        IOException futureException = null;

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            streamException = e;
        }

        try {
            future.get(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            futureException = new BoxIOException("donwload interrupted", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            futureException = new BoxIOException("download failure",
                e.getCause());
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            futureException = new BoxIOException("download cancelled", e);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            futureException = new BoxIOException("download timeout", e);
        }

        if (futureException != null) {
            if (streamException != null)
                futureException.addSuppressed(streamException);
            throw futureException;
        }

        if (streamException != null)
            throw streamException;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void mark(final int readlimit)
    {
        in.mark(readlimit);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void reset()
        throws IOException
    {
        try {
            in.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            throw new BoxIOException("download failure", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean markSupported()
    {
        return in.markSupported();
    }
}
```

The code consistenly fails with the following stack trace (that is in `int read(byte[])`:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.fge.filesystem.box.exceptions.BoxIOException: download failure
    at com.github.fge.filesystem.box.io.BoxFileInputStream.read(BoxFileInputStream.java:81)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2735)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2854)
    at java.nio.file.CopyMoveHelper.copyToForeignTarget(CopyMoveHelper.java:126)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1230)
    at Main.main(Main.java:37)
    [ IDEA specific stack trace elements follow -- irrelevant]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe broken
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:322)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:378)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.github.fge.filesystem.box.io.BoxFileInputStream.read(BoxFileInputStream.java:78)
    ... 10 more
```

But when it fails, the download is already complete...

OK, the thing is, I can grab the file size and hack around it but I'd prefer not to if at all possible; how can I modify this code so as to avoid EPIPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK also provides [`BoxAPIRequest`](http://opensource.box.com/box-java-sdk/javadoc/com/box/sdk/BoxAPIRequest.html) and [`BoxAPIResponse`](http://opensource.box.com/box-java-sdk/javadoc/com/box/sdk/BoxAPIResponse.html) classes that let you make manual requests for advanced use-cases. These classes still automatically handle authentication, errors, back-off, etc. but give you more granular control over the request.

In your case, you could do make a [download request](https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-download-a-file) manually by doing:

```
// Note: this example assumes you already have a BoxAPIConnection.
URL url = new URL("files/" + file.getID() + "/content")
BoxAPIRequest request = new BoxAPIRequest(api, url, "GET");
BoxAPIResponse response = request.send();

InputStream bodyStream = response.getBody();
// Use the stream.
response.disconnect();
```

Comment: Interesting! I will look into these... I gather the same is possible for uploads, right? If I can avoid the use of pipes altogether, I'll jump for it!

Comment: Yes, you can also get a raw stream for uploads - however uploads are more complicated because they must be multipart requests. There's a `BoxMultipartRequest` class, but again, it only supports InputStreams. You'll have to format a multipart request yourself in order to support writing the file contents to the body in the correct place. The [source](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/box/sdk/BoxMultipartRequest.java) of `BoxMultipartRequest` might be of some help if you decide to go this route.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution, although I am not very satisfied with it...

Since I can know the file size which I try to open an inputstream on, I just pick the size and decrease it by the amount of bytes read -- unless the size reaches 0, in this case all read methods return -1.